# AsyncAwait causes unexpected method behavior, Methods runs in wrong thread if called from constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, task, async-await

I'm trying to do some time consuming actions without freezing the GUI Thread. The `UpdateSomething` Method is called in two places once in the constructor of my ViewModel and once on button click (RelayCommand). The Method is executed in a WorkerThread if the method is called via RelayCommand, but runs in the MainThread (GUI) when the method call comes from the constructor.

What causes this *strange* behavior? I double check a few times via IntelliTrace.

This is the method in question:

```
private async void UpdateSomething()
{
    var item = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>this.DoSomething("I should run async"));
    this.TestItem = item;
}
```

I'm using WPF and .Net 4.5

Comment: Could you please add your solution as answer with explanation? It could be helpful for other people too :)

Comment: the user @Rene147 answered this question and i marked his answer as the correct one. Unfortunately he deleted his answer for some reasons i do not know.

Comment: You should read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: Thank you @ChuckRostance, i will have a read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case where the `Task`s action runs on the main thread, the most likely cause is that the method `UpdateSomething` is being called from within another `Task` (a `Task` that was scheduled to run on the main thread).  In that case, the `TaskScheduler.Current` is the main thread `TaskScheduler` not the `TaskScheduler.Default` which queues work to the thread pool.

`Task.Factory.StartNew` defaults to using `TaskScheduler.Current` (you can change what it uses by calling the appropriate override), while `Task.Run` uses `TaskScheduler.Default`.

The statement that `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't play will with async/await is not correct, it's just that some of the defaults are probably not what you want for the common case (this is part of why`Task.Run` was introduced).

See:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx
- [Why is TaskScheduler.Current the default TaskScheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800705/why-is-taskscheduler-current-the-default-taskscheduler)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem a while ago.  I stuck up a little post about it [here](http://blog.reneorban.com/2013/04/awaiting-taskfactorystartnew.html):

> Today I had a major hair pulling moment. I was using a await/async on a block of code wrapped in a new task. No matter what I did it would just start the Task but then not wait for the result.
>
> After much frustration I worked out that using `await Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't play well with await.
>
> In the end I simply changed it to [Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) what was then worked fine.

Basically you need to use [Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) instead because `await` doesn't play nicely with `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: For an explanation of the differences, see [`Task.Run` vs `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered by @Rene147 but he deleted his answer. (for whatever reason)

I will briefly rephrase what he had written:

await/asycn doesn't play very well with `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Simply replace `Task.Factory.StartNew` by `Task.Run` and everything should work:

```
private async void UpdateSomething()
{
    //not working when call comes from constructor
    //var item = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>this.DoSomething("I should run async"));
    //working
    var item = await Task.Run(() =>this.DoSomething("I run async!"));
    this.TestItem = item;
}
```

Rene147 also wrote a short [blogpost](http://blog.reneorban.com/2013/04/awaiting-taskfactorystartnew.html) about it.

Would be happy to get more information about this issue, still seems odd to me.

Comment: A moderator deleted Rene's answer... I'm guessing it's because someone flagged it as a link-only answer or spam, so I made an edit to the answer to move the content from the link into the answer, and have flagged it to be undeleted. Moderators really shouldn't be deleting useful, upvoted, and accepted answers to questions, especially when they are the only answer there, and they actually answer the question.