# Does Task.ContinueWith capture the calling thread context for continuation?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

The `Test_Click` below is a simplified version of code which runs on a UI thread (with [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx)):

```
void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = DoNavigationAsync();
    task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Navigation done!");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Should I explicitly specify `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to make sure the continuation action will be executed on the same UI thread? Or does `ContinueWith` capture the execution context automatically (thus, making `TaskScheduler` argument redundant in this case)?

I assume it doesn't do it by default (unlike `await`), but so far I could not find an online resource to confirm this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't use the current synchronization context by default, but `TaskScheduler.Current`, as seen in the following decompiled code:

```
public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task<TResult>> continuationAction)
{
  StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
  return this.ContinueWith(continuationAction, TaskScheduler.Current, new CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.None, ref stackMark);
}
```

`TaskScheduler.Current` is either `TaskScheduler.Default` or the TaskScheduler of the current task if the task is a child task. Always specify the task scheduler if you don't want to run into [weird problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800705/why-is-taskscheduler-current-the-default-taskscheduler), or better, use `await` if you can.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. I've also found [this](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/09/29/C-Async-Tips-and-Tricks-Part-3-Tasks-and-the-Synchronization-Context.aspx), related and very helpful.

Comment: Even easier to find now with the reference source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#27c5b7fbe5caaa18

That being said, could you please explain what the StackCrawlMark does?