# WebAPI HttpContext is Null Inside ContinueWith() => tast

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm just wondering if someone could explain what is happening here.

Given this Post method on an API controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostImage()
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    var c = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {            
        Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = task.Result;
            foreach (HttpContent content in provider.Contents)
            {
                Stream stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                var uploadFileName = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;

                var requestInside = HttpContext.Current.Request;  // this is always null    

                string filePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserFilesRootDir"]), userprofile.UserCode);

                //string[] headerValues = (string[])Request.Headers.GetValues("UniqueId");

                string fileName = userprofile.UserCode + ".jpg";

                string fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

                image.Save(fullPath);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Why would `var requestInside = HttpContext.Current.Request;` be null?

I've checked all the relevant settings:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
...

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"
```

And `SynchronizationContext.Current` is the newer `AspNetSynchronizationContext` rather than `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext`.

I'm presuming at the moment that it's because I'm on a different thread, is this a correct assumption?

Comment: I am curious. Why not use the async/await operators so that the Request context is captured on resume of execution after an async method completes? So mark the method signature `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostImage`

Comment: Sure, I'm still working on this code and will do that, but just curious.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link on `ContinueWith` and how you could probably get it to work with just that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContinueWith` is not guaranteed to run on the same thread hence the synchronization context could be lost. You could change your call to specify to resume on the current thread with parameter `TaskScheduler.Current`. [See this previous SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313093/1260204)

If you use await/async pattern it will automatically capture the current syncronization context on resume once an awaitable operation completes. This is done by resuming the operation on the same thread which is bound to that context. An added benefit, IMHO, is cleaner looking code.

You can change your code to this which uses that pattern. *I have not made any other changes to it other than use async/await.*

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostImage()
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    var c = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());
        foreach (HttpContent content in provider.Contents)
        {
            Stream stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            var uploadFileName = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;

            var requestInside = HttpContext.Current.Request;  // this is always null    

            string filePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserFilesRootDir"]), userprofile.UserCode);

            //string[] headerValues = (string[])Request.Headers.GetValues("UniqueId");

            string fileName = userprofile.UserCode + ".jpg";

            string fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

            image.Save(fullPath);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Indeed this makes sense, my original assumption (based on the ContinueWith) was correct.  Thanks Igor.